# How to show Power BI dashboard in MVC application without using Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, powerbi

I am novice user of Power-BI and trying to learn the possibilities of Power-BI integration with custom  business solution developed in MVC.

Is there any way we can show power-BI Dashboards in an MVC application without using Azure.

Answer (score 1):

We support embedding tiles and reports in applications.  Embedding dashboards is on our roadmap. The tile and report API is browser based and uses standard REST APIs to get the required information to embed the tiles/reports.  You can definitely make that work in MVC.  The [samples, one for tiles and another for reports](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-CSharp/tree/master/samples/webforms), are available on GitHub.